# BSOD's when gaming. Freshly built PC, windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, drivers, bsod, computer-building, gaming

Here are text files of the analysis I got from the Windows debugger: https://www.mediafire.com/folder/m2cxget7qsop6/Dump_text

I just built a pc and I get a lot of different BSOD's when starting up GTA V.

```
GPU: EVGA GTX 980 SUPERCLOCKED ACX 2.0
CPU: Intel i5 4690K (stock fan)
Motherboard: Asus z97-K
Memory: Kingston 8gb DDR3
HDD: WD Black 1tb
PSU: Corsair CX600M
```

I updated all drivers on the pc to the newest available, I am NOT overclocking. Checked for viruses, PC is clean.

Here's a sample of one of the WHEA errors:

```
WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)

A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error

source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the

WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.

Arguments:

Arg1: 0000000000000000, Machine Check Exception

Arg2: ffffe00001dd8028, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.

Arg3: 00000000bf800000, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

Arg4: 0000000000000124, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

Debugging Details:

------------------

BUGCHECK_STR: 0x124_GenuineIntel

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID: WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME: csrss.exe

CURRENT_IRQL: f

STACK_TEXT:

nt!KeBugCheckEx
hal!HalBugCheckSystem+0xcf
nt!WheaReportHwError+0x22d
hal!HalpMcaReportError+0x50
hal!HalpMceHandlerCore+0xe1
hal!HalpMceHandler+0xe4
hal!HalpMceHandlerWithRendezvous+0xce
hal!HalHandleMcheck+0x40
nt!KxMcheckAbort+0x7b
nt!KiMcheckAbort+0x171
win32k!PushW32ThreadLock+0x3b
win32k!xxxUserPowerCalloutWorker+0x74
win32k!NtUserCallNoParam+0x2e
nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
0x00007ffc`a13e17ea

STACK_COMMAND: kb

FOLLOWUP_NAME: MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: GenuineIntel

IMAGE_NAME: GenuineIntel

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP: 0

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID: 0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_CACHE

BUCKET_ID: 0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_CACHE

Followup: MachineOwner

---------
```

Comment: Is this issue only prevalent for GTA V or any graphics demanding game? How long after loading GTA V do you get the BSOD? I'm going to take a shot in the dark here and say there's an issue with your Intel ChipSet drivers, you sure you installed the right ones? Either that, or there's an issue with GC drivers. I would double check those, get some temperatures of the CPU/GPU cores, post those. In addition double checking that you have all Windows updates can help with drivers.

Comment: run **!errrec ffffe00001dd8028** and post the output here.

Comment: What you’re seeing here is a true hardware error. The CPU’s continuous self-diagnosis function has determined that the CPU can no longer function normally. I’ll look into the docs to decode the `MCi_STATUS` value.

Comment: In decoded the error, [here’s the result](http://pastebin.com/LutEwu3C). Because I’m not familiar with this specific error, I’m not posting this as an answer. I cannot tell whether it definitely means the CPU is broken. Yes, even genuine newly-acquired CPUs can be broken.

Comment: @DanielB Hi! Thanks for your feedback, I think everything is fixed now, I updated my BIOS and everything is fine now!

Comment: Make sure to make that a proper answer! You can then accept your own answer after a set amount of time, 1 day IIRC. That way this question will be marked as answered, otherwise the system will keep pushing it from time to time.

Comment: For future reference, with Intel 124 bugcheck tends to be memory management related. Might be that the old BIOS was supplying too little voltage relative to the CPU's VID tables.

Answer (score 0):

Updated BIOS, everything works!